# Presto: Cast different schema on JSON column

Tags: mongodb, presto

I have a MongoDB collection which is also imported into Presto. 
The collection consists of the following fields:

- id: string
- type: string
- data: json
- timestamp: timestamp

The data field may receive different JSON data, depending on the type field. 
When imported to Presto, I ran `show columns` command in presto, and got the following result:

```
row(user bigint, type varchar, mode varchar, status boolean)
```

However, this JSON schema only applies to a certain type of data, while for other types I get NULL 'data' results on every SELECT query on this table.

Is it possible to cast the data field to a certain format per query? e.g. with format 
`row(user bigint, event bigint, mode varchar, channel varchar, time timestamp, metadata array(varchar))`? 
Any example would be helpful.

Comment: Do i understand correctly that mapping to `user, type, mode, status` is something defined in connector configuration? Did you try mapping single mongodb collection several times, with different type mapping?

Comment: No. In the presto connector configuration i only provided the host, port and collection name. This mapping appeared on presto afterwards, not sure how this is defined. Perhaps after parsing a few data?